# Best way to strip quotation marks from form input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form input that I'm going to process:

```
<tr class="formulaRow">
<input type="text" class="ingredient required" name="ingredient">
</tr>
```

I currently store the value from this input like this:

```
var ingredient = $(".formulaRow").find(".ingredient").val();
```

When I save this to an array, the value always stores as "something" with quotation marks around it.

What's the best way to remove these quotation marks using jquery?

Comment: " the value always stores as "something" with quotation marks around it." --- how do you know that?

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc7u9jpc/2/) the outputs the value of the textbox onto the page. You'll notice that the actual value does not have quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotation marks are meant to be there to state that it is a string.

Eg. ["beef"] is an array with a single element containing the string beef. This is normal.

The " are not actually part of the string, and are impossible to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are pulling in double quotes to that variable, you can use this notation to check for all `"` then replace them with essentially nothing:

```
var ingredient = $(".formulaRow").find(".ingredient").val();
var noQuotes = ingredient.replace(/["]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read a value from an array string, and use the value in any part of your code or display it using an html control, `"` will not be visible. These quotation marks are just to tell that the array is containing `string` type values (or objects). For example, in the following example, when you view the page in the browser, you will see only `a` not `"a"` attached to the `span`.

```
  <span id="display"></span>

  var ingredient = ["a", 'b'];

  $("#display").html(ingredient[0]);
```